# How to Sort Number, Date, Currency columns with jQuery Data-tables

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using jQuery data-table to show some data in a table. My table contains data like, string, currency, date, and numbers.

When I try to sort the date, currency, and number columns, data-table thinks it's a string and sorts it. But I want to sort by there types.

```
col1  | col2       | col3
Jack  | 2013-12-23 | 10,230
Jack2 | 2013-11-1  | 1,480
```

I have looked on Google and the official website, all are discussing about some code, but I am new to data tables, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here's a sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/831/) using the [DataTables sorting plugin](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) to sort columns with Date and comma-formatted numeric values.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numeric-comma-pre": function (a) {
        var x = (a == "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/,/, ".");
        return parseFloat(x);
    },

        "numeric-comma-asc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

        "numeric-comma-desc": function (a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    },
        'us_date-asc': function (a, b) {
        var x = new Date(a),
            y = new Date(b);
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    'us_date-desc' : function (a, b) {
        var x = new Date(a),
            y = new Date(b);
        return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aoColumns": [
               {"sType": "us_date"},
               null,
               null, 
               {"sType": "numeric-comma"},
               null]
    });
});
```

In this demo, I have not included the sorting plugin. Instead, I have extended the sorting functionality by adding the sorting plugin code inline.